# Bash - how to sort negative values?

Tags: bash, sorting

is there a way to sort negative numbers with sort in bash ? I have sin written out

```
...
0.250109
0.188852
0.126850
0.064349
0.001593
-0.061168
-0.123689
-0.185722
-0.247023
-0.307349
...
```

and the problem is when I run sort on it, it just sorts it by values - regardless of the minus in front of some values. Is there a way to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Use `sort -n` with the `-n` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem was that the data wasnt well formatted - because of my locale, I had to sed decimal point into decimal comma - that's how its written in czech republic
thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11957619)

Comment: well yes, I am the author and the problem was indeed my locale settings

Answer (score 11):

Use `sort -g` (`--general-numeric-sort`), not `sort -n` (`--numeric-sort`).

See [sort Invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) for an explanation of the subtle differences between these two options.